# Pythagorean triple in Haskell without symmetrical solutions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I gotta do the Pythagorean triple in Haskell without symmetrical solutions. My try is:

```
terna :: Int -> [(Int,Int,Int)]
terna x = [(a,b,c)|a<-[1..x], b<-[1..x], c<-[1..x], (a^2)+(b^2) == (c^2)]
```

and I get as a result:

```
Main> terna 10
[(3,4,5),(4,3,5),(6,8,10),(8,6,10)]
```

As you can see, I´m getting symmetrical solutions like: (3,4,5) (4,3,5). I need to get rid of them but I don´t know how. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 13):

Every time you have a duplicate you have one version in which a is greater than b and one where b is greater than a. So if you want to make sure you only ever get one of them, you just need to make sure that either `a` is always equal to or less than `b` or vice versa.

One way to achieve this would be to add it as a condition to the list comprehension.

Another, more efficient way, would be to change `b`'s generator to `b <- [1..a]`, so it only generates values for `b` which are smaller or equal to `a`.

Speaking of efficiency: There is no need to iterate over `c` at all. Once you have values for `a` and `b`, you could simply calculate `(a^2)+(b^2)` and check whether it has a natural square root.

Comment: you do not need <=, just < since sqrt(2) is irrational number :D

Answer (score 5):

Don't know Haskell at all (perhaps you're learning it now?) but it seems like you could get rid of them if you could take only the ones for which `a` is less than or equal to `b`.  That would get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: Or you could avoid generating them to begin with by saying `b<-[1..a]`. Speaking of which, this is really inefficient for a bunch of other reasons too, if that matters :-)

Comment: also, you can speed things up by only considering values of c s.t. c > a+b.

Comment: @rampion That doesn't make sense.  Consider the triangle of `a = 3, b = 4, c = 5`.  Perhaps you ment `c < a + b`?  Or perhaps you wanted `c < (a^2 + b^2)^(0.5)`?

Comment: Thomas: you're right. typo when trying to write the triangle inequality

Answer (score 4):

Try with a simple recursive generator:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples

(new article)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples

**EDIT** (7 May 2014)

Here I have made infinite generator that can generate primitive triplets ordered by perimeter (but can be modified to be ordered by other parameter - hypotenuses, area, ...) as long as it holds that any triplet is  smaller that any generated from generator matrix according to provided compare function

```
import Data.List -- for mmult

merge f x [] = x
merge f [] y = y
merge f (x:xs) (y:ys)
               | f x y     =  x : merge f xs     (y:ys) 
               | otherwise =  y : merge f (x:xs) ys 


mmult :: Num a => [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]] 
mmult a b = [ [ sum $ zipWith (*) ar bc | bc <- (transpose b) ] | ar <- a ]

tpgen_matrix = [[[ 1,-2, 2],[ 2 ,-1, 2],[ 2,-2, 3]],
                [[ 1, 2, 2],[ 2 , 1, 2],[ 2, 2, 3]],
                [[-1, 2, 2],[-2 , 1, 2],[-2, 2, 3]]]

matrixsum  =  sum . map sum
tripletsorter x y =  ( matrixsum  x ) < ( matrixsum y ) -- compare perimeter

triplegen_helper b =  foldl1 
            ( merge tripletsorter ) 
            [ h : triplegen_helper h | x <- tpgen_matrix , let h = mmult x b ]

triplets =  x : triplegen_helper x  where x = [[3],[4],[5]]

main =  mapM print $ take 10 triplets
```

Comment: Nice. Can one of those formulas be written easily in Haskell? ;)

Comment: The tree of primitive pythagorean triples is really easy in Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
pythagorean = [ (x,y,m*m+n*n) | 
                                m <- [2..], 
                                n <- [1 .. m-1], 
                                let x = m*m-n*n, 
                                let y = 2*m*n ]
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work: [Got it from this tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#ready-set-go)

```
triangles x = [(a,b,c) | c <- [1..x], b <- [1..c], a <- [1..b] , a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

Answer (score -1):

List comprehension syntax makes this easy:

```
triplets :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer, Integer)]
triplets d = [(a,b,c) | a <- [1..d], b <- [a..d], c <- [b..d], a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

This basically says than we build a list from `a`s,`b`s and `c`s, where `a` changes from `1` to `d`, `b` changes from current `a` to `d` and etc. It also says that `a^2 + b^2 == c^2` should hold.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).